# Retraction of disk minus a point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

For any $p\in D^2$ consider $D^2\setminus\{ p\}$.

I am trying to show this retracts to the circle $S^1$ so that I can show $D^2\setminus\{ p\}$ does not have the fixed point property, since $S^1$ does and it is conserved by a retraction.

I can see that if $p$ is in the interior of the disk then the map $x\mapsto \frac{x} {\| x \|} $ is a retraction, but I cannot see how this would work with $p \in \partial D^2$.

Is there an explicit retraction? And if not is there another way to approach this question?

Comment: This feels like it ought to deformation retract to the open interval.

Comment: If $p \in \partial D^2$, then $D^2 \setminus \{p\}$ is contractible, thus $S^1$ is not a retract of it. (With standard notation, $S^1$ is not even a subset of $D^2 \setminus \{p\}$ for $p$ a boundary point, but since $D^2\setminus \{p\}$ is then contractible, no embedded $S^1$ can be a retract.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be in the interior of $D^2$. For any $x\in D^2\setminus \{p\}$ consider the ray from $p$ to $x$. This is given by $p + t(x-p)$ for $t\in[0,\infty)$ and there exists a unique $t_0\in(0,\infty)$ such that $\|p+t_0(x-p)\| = 1$. We define a map $f\colon D^2\setminus\{p\}\to S^1$, $x\mapsto p+t_0(x-p)$. This is well defined, continuous (one  can work out an explicit formula) and if $\|x\|=1$, then $f(x)=x$. So $f$ is a retraction.

Note that if $p\in\partial D^2$, the map $f$ gives a retraction of  $D^2\setminus\{p\}$ to $S^1\setminus\{p\}$ which is contractible.