# Retraction of $(n+1)$-skeleton minus the center of $n+1$-cells on $n-$skeleton

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

It is a well known fact that the closed disk $\mathbb{D}^n$ minus for example its center, deformation retracts onto the border $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, for example this argument can be generalized to the $n$ dimensional case [Retraction of disk minus a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432617/retraction-of-disk-minus-a-point).

I was wondering whether in a $CW$ setup, there is a similar fact. Specifically I'm asking whether is possible to write explicitly a deformation retract of the $n+1$ skeleton $X^{n+1}$ minus the center of $(n+1)$-cells on the $n-$ skeleton $X^n$.

I think the idea should use the fact that we know an explicit retraction of the disk minus a point on its border, but I'm not sure how to well define the maps even just to prove the continuity, since we have identifications given by characteristic maps, and maybe family of maps to deal with, which are not so intuitive to me.

I need this "fact" in order to prove that $(X,X^n)$ is $n-$connected if $X$ is a $CW$ complex, any hint,help solution or reference would be appreciated.

**Edit** : I thought to use the deformation retraction given by $H(x,t) = (1-t)x+t\frac{x}{\lvert\lvert x \rvert \rvert}$ for every disk $\mathbb{D}_\alpha^n$ with center $\vec{0}_\alpha$ and costruct the following diagram $$\begin{array}{cc}
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,X^n - \bigsqcup_\alpha\phi_{\alpha}(\vec{0_\alpha}) \\
\\
\ \pi \uparrow & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\searrow \,{\simeq} \\
\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\left( \bigsqcup_\alpha \mathbb{D}_\alpha^n - \phi_{\alpha}(\vec{0_\alpha}) \right) \sqcup X^{n-1} & \xrightarrow{r}  & X^{n-1}
\end{array}$$

Where $r$ is defined through the deformation retracts as $\begin{cases} \varphi_{\alpha}\circ r_{\alpha}(x) & x \not\in X^{n-1} \\ x & x \in X^{n-1} \end{cases}$

**Issues** : Is $r$ continuos or even well defined? Taking the equivalence relation on $\left( \bigsqcup_\alpha \mathbb{D}_\alpha^n - \phi_{\alpha}(\vec{0_\alpha}) \right) \sqcup X^{n-1}$ really yields to $X^n - \bigsqcup_\alpha\phi_{\alpha}(\vec{0_\alpha})?$ Last but not least, I don't if this map induces the homotopy equivalence $\simeq$ on the right of the diagram I'm hoping for.

Comment: Yes, it is well defined, and yes the equivalence relation really induces what you've written. That's because interioris of cells do not take part in creating a quotient (adjunction) space. Meaning no point in an interior is related to any other point. In particular interiors of cells are disjoint. Continuity is a bit harder, but the weak topology implies that a function defined on whole CW complex is continuous if and only if it is continuous when restricted to each cell. That should give you a good start.

Comment: @freakish Thanks, what about the homotopy equivalence?

Comment: Well, if $e_i$ is a cell and $t_i=e_i\backslash\{x_i\}$ for some interior point $x_i\in int(e_i)$, then you start with a deformation retraction $H_i:I\times t_i\to t_i$ onto the boundary. Then you glue all those deformation retractions: $H(t,x)=H_i(t,x)$ if $x\in int(e_i)$ and $H(t,x)=x$ otherwise. You need them to be strong deformation retractions, i.e. $H_i(t,x)=x$ whenever $x\in\partial e_i$.

Comment: @freakish Understood,thanks. In this problem continuity is the cliff, I see

Comment: Be warned though: I used the "glue" word, but the continuity does not follow from the glueing lemma, because we can have infinitely many cells (and not necessarily locally finite). Again: the weak topology of CW has to be applied here.

Comment: @freakish Feel free to write an answer if it seems reasonably easy or fast to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X^{n+1}$ be the $n+1$-skeleton and $\Phi_{\alpha}\colon D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\rightarrow X^{n+1},\,\alpha\in A$ the $n+1$-cells. Then $X^{n+1}$ with the centers of the $n+1$-cells removed is the space $X^{n+1}\setminus\{\Phi_{\alpha}(0)\colon\alpha\in A\}$. This is the disjoint union of its subspaces $X^n=X^{n+1}\setminus\{\Phi_{\alpha}(\mathrm{int}(D_{\alpha}^{n+1}))\colon\alpha\in A\}$ (here, I'm identifying $X^n$ with its copy in $X^{n+1}$ as is usual) and $\Phi_{\alpha}(\mathrm{int}(D_{\alpha}^{n+1})\setminus\{0\}),\,\alpha\in A$. Let $H\colon(D^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times I\rightarrow D^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ be a strong deformation retraction of $D^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ onto $S^n$. Now, we want to construct a strong deformation retraction $\tilde{H}\colon(X^{n+1}\setminus\{\Phi_{\alpha}(0)\colon\alpha\in A\})\times I\rightarrow X^{n+1}\setminus\{\Phi_{\alpha}(0)\colon\alpha\in A\}$ of $X^{n+1}\setminus\{\Phi_{\alpha}(0)\colon\alpha\in A\}$ onto $X^n$. The idea is to push forward the homotopy $H$ through the $\Phi_{\alpha},\,\alpha\in A$ while leaving $X^n$ fixed, though some care needs to be taken at the boundaries.

Let us define $\tilde{H}(x,t)=x$ for $(x,t)\in X^n\times I$ and $\tilde{H}(x,t)=\Phi_{\alpha}(H(\Phi_{\alpha}^{-1}(x),t))$ for $(x,t)\in\Phi_{\alpha}(\mathrm{int}(D_{\alpha}^{n+1})\setminus\{0\})\times I,\,\alpha\in A$ (note that $\Phi_{\alpha}\vert_{\mathrm{int}(D_{\alpha}^{n+1})}\colon\mathrm{int}(D_{\alpha}^{n+1})\rightarrow X^{n+1}$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, whose inverse is what I mean by $\Phi_{\alpha}^{-1}$). By construction, $\tilde{H}(-,0)$ is the identity, $\tilde{H}(x,t)=x$ for any $(x,t)\in X^n\times I$ and $\tilde{H}(-,1)$ is a retraction of $X^{n+1}\setminus\{\Phi_{\alpha}(0)\colon\alpha\in A\}$ onto $X^n$ (since $\tilde{H}(\Phi_{\alpha}(\mathrm{int}(D_{\alpha}^{n+1})\setminus\{0\})\times\{1\})\subseteq\Phi_{\alpha}(S^n)\subseteq X^n$ for all $\alpha\in A$). It remains to check that $\tilde{H}$ is continuous.

By definition of the CW topology, there is a quotient map $X^n\sqcup\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\rightarrow X^{n+1}$. Since $I$ is compact, $\left(X^n\sqcup\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\right)\times I\rightarrow X^{n+1}\times I$ is a quotient map. Furthermore, $\left(X^n\sqcup\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\right)\times I\cong(X^n\times I)\sqcup\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}(D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\times I)$ via the obvious map. Altogether, we obtain a quotient map $(X^n\times I)\sqcup\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}(D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\times I)\rightarrow X^{n+1}\times I$, which restricts to a quotient map $r\colon(X^n\times I)\sqcup\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}((D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times I)\rightarrow(X^{n+1}\setminus\{\Phi_{\alpha}(0)\colon\alpha\in A\})\times I$. Chasing the definitions, this is given by $r(x,t)=(x,t)$ for $(x,t)\in X^n\times I$ and $r(x,t)=(\Phi_{\alpha}(x),t)$ for $(x,t)\in(D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times I$. Since $r$ is a quotient map, it suffices to check continuity of $\tilde{H}\circ r$. By definition of the coproduct topology, it suffices to check the continuity of $\tilde{H}\circ r\vert_{X^n\times I}$ and $\tilde{H}\circ r\vert_{D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\times I}$ for all $\alpha\in A$. For $(x,t)\in X^n\times I$, we have $\tilde{H}(r(x,t))=\tilde{H}(x,t)=x$, whence $\tilde{H}\circ r\vert_{X^n\times I}$ is simply the composition $X^n\times I\rightarrow X^n\rightarrow X^{n+1}$ of projection followed by inclusion, i.e. continuous. For $(x,t)\in(D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times I$, we have
$$\tilde{H}(r(x,t))=\tilde{H}(\Phi_{\alpha}(x),t)=\left.\begin{cases}\Phi_{\alpha}(x),&x\in S_{\alpha}^n,\\\Phi_{\alpha}(H(x,t)),&x\in\mathrm{int}(D^{n+1})\setminus\{0\}\end{cases}\right\}=\Phi_{\alpha}(H(x,t)).$$
In the last equality, we have used that $H$ is a strong deformation retraction.
Thus, $\tilde{H}\circ r\vert_{(D_{\alpha}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times I}=\Phi_{\alpha}\circ H$ is continuous. In conclusion, $\tilde{H}$ is continuous and thus a strong deformation retraction.

Comment: The restriction that defines $r$ is a quotient map? In general the restriction of a quotient map is not a quotient map, It works in this particular case?

Comment: If $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map and $Y^{\prime}\subseteq Y$ is open, the restriction $f\vert_{f^{-1}(Y^{\prime})}\colon f^{-1}(Y^{\prime})\rightarrow Y^{\prime}$ is a quotient map as well.

Comment: Are you able to prove [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218048/proof-of-cellular-approximation-theorem) continuity? Seems that everyone is avoiding it